# Show that an ideal is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

**Problem**

Given a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a representation $\rho: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, define
\begin{align}
B_\rho: \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} & \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\ (X,Y) & \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(\rho(X) \circ \rho(Y)).
\end{align}
Let $R(B_\rho)$ be the radical of $B_\rho$, namely
\begin{align}
R(B_\rho) := \{X \in \mathfrak{g} : B_\rho(X,Y) = 0, \ \forall \ Y \in \mathfrak{g}\}.
\end{align}
I am trying to show that the image of $R(B)$ through $\rho$ is solvable.

**Attempt**

Fix $I = \{\rho(X) : X \in R(B_\rho)\}$. Given the derived series
\begin{align*}
    I^{(1)} \supseteq I^{(2)} \supseteq I^{(3)} \supseteq \ldots
\end{align*}
in which $I^{(1)} = I$ and $I^{(n)} : = [I^{n-1}, I^{n-1}]$, the problem will be solved if there is some $n >> 0$ such that $I^{(n)} = \{0\}$. Since $[\rho(X),\rho(X_0)] = \rho([X,X_0])$, one can write
\begin{align*}
I^{(2)} = \{\rho([X,X_0]): X,X_0 \in R(B_\rho)\}.
\end{align*}
It follows inductively that
\begin{align}
    I^{(n)} = \{\rho([X,X_0]) : X,X_0 \in R(B_\rho)^{(n - 1)}\}.
\end{align}

Thus, my problem will be gone if I can show that $R(B_\rho)$ is solvable.

**Questions**

1. I am stuck. How can I show that $R(B_\rho)$ is solvable.
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem? If yes, I would rather have a hint on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the image of $R(B_\rho)$ is solvable, follows from the Cartan Criterion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion